# Maven 2.6 exception error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I got the following error in *Eclipse* when I try to run the *project--> Clean*:

> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6

Comment: Proxy/Firewall issue?

Comment: Has this ever worked?  The version number may be bad.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this issue and I resolved it by following the next step:

1- Close Eclipse.

2- Go to the user directory and delete the .m2 directory.

3- Open Eclipse.

4 - Now got to the menu Project -> Select Clean

5- Once done, Select the project and click refresh and run the maven install.

Comment: Will not help, cause the dependencies can't be downloaded as the message already stated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to download the jars properly by the command "mvn -u clean install" from your project directory using command line. Then try to rebuild the project. It will help you I think.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Steps Followed Updated proper **Setting.XML**file in my Machine ,
 Restarted Eclipse
Issue Resolved